# I want to set the winning day of the event as a weekday, but is it possible to resolve the error?

Tags: php

```
// holiday array
$holy = [
    '2020-12-23',
    '2020-12-24',
    '2020-12-25',
    '2020-12-28',
    '2020-12-29',
    ];



$inputDate = '2020-12-23'; // input
$outputDate = get_date($inputDate);

echo "Winning Day: " . $outputDate . "<br />";
echo "<br />";


function get_date($chkDate)
{
    global $holy;

    $chkDateYoil = date("w", strtotime($chkDate)); // sat(6), sun(0)


    if ($chkDateYoil == 6) {
        // Saturday when  + 2
        $timestamp = strtotime($chkDate . " +2 days");
        $chkDate = date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);

    } else if ($chkDateYoil == 0) {
        // Sunday when  + 1
        $timestamp = strtotime($chkDate . " +1 days");
        $chkDate = date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);

    }
    // If it's a weekday, compare it array
    foreach ($holy as $key => $holyday) {
        if ($chkDate == $holyday) {
            // holiday when + 1
            $day_plus = 8 - $chkDateYoil;
            $timestamp = strtotime($chkDate." +".$day_plus." days");
            $chkDate = date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
        }

    }


    return $chkDate;
}
```

Hello, let me ask a question.

The following codes are:

Is the input value weekend?
Or are they included in the array?
in accordance with the judgment

Weekday extraction code.

But there is an error.

in my estimation

December 30th is supposed to come out.

By the way, January 2, 2021 is the result.

Why is that?

sorry

i don't write english very well

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line: `$day_plus = 8 - $chkDateYoil;`, which is calculating the date of the next Monday the first time it's executed.

You're then looping through the rest of the `$holy` array, and updating `$chkDate` if necessary, but you're not recalculating the value of `$chkDateYoil`, so the output depends on the day of the week you run this. Today (23rd December) it stops on `2nd January`

Your code can be simplified by just incrementing the date by 1 day and performing the checks again, continuing until you get a result. I've also used the PHP function `in_array()` to simplify the search of the `$holy` array, and incorporated it into the same test as Saturday and Sunday.

```
// holiday array
$holy = [
    '2020-12-23',
    '2020-12-24',
    '2020-12-25',
    '2020-12-28',
    '2020-12-29',
];



$inputDate = '2020-12-23'; // input
$outputDate = get_date($inputDate);

echo "Winning Day: " . $outputDate . "<br />";
echo "<br />";


function get_date($chkDate)
{
    global $holy;
    do {
        $chkDateYoil = date("w", strtotime($chkDate)); // sat(6), sun(0)
        if (($chkDateYoil == 0) || ($chkDateYoil == 6) || (in_array($chkDate, $holy))) {
            $timestamp = strtotime($chkDate . " +1 days");
            $chkDate = date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
        } else {
            return $chkDate;
        }

    } while (true);

}
```

Comment: amazing!!
I've been thinking about it all day. 
Thank you so much for your care. 
i don't have to pack because of you. 
thank you so much!!